# Mule Java SDK Connector - Tests - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: maven, testing, dependencies

I built a (default) Mule 4 connector with the Mule Java SDK using mule-module-batch-ee (4.5.0-20220622).

To build the 'mule-basic-extension' project (test project), I used the command `mvn org.mule.extensions:mule-extensions-archetype-maven-plugin:1.2.0:generate`. I only changed is the pom.xml file.
When I try to build my project using `mvn install`, I get this error durring testing:

```
C:\Users\{user}\AnypointStudio\studio-workspace\mule-basic-extension>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------< org.mule.extension:mule-basic-extension >---------------
[INFO] Building Basic Extension 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] ---------------------------[ mule-extension ]---------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- processor:2.2.4:process (process) @ mule-basic-extension ---
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ mule-basic-extension ---
[INFO] Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ mule-basic-extension ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mule-extensions:1.1.6:extension-descriptor (default-extension-descriptor) @ mule-basic-extension ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ mule-basic-extension ---
[INFO] Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mule-basic-extension ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ mule-basic-extension ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.mule.extension.BasicOperationsTestCase
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.551 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.mule.extension.BasicOperationsTestCase
[ERROR] initializationError(org.mule.extension.BasicOperationsTestCase)  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mule.runtime.api.deployment.meta.MuleServiceModel.getServiceProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   BasicOperationsTestCase.initializationError » NoSuchMethod org.mule.runtime.ap...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.443 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-05T08:46:44+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project mule-basic-extension: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\{user}\AnypointStudio\studio-workspace\mule-basic-extension\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**surefire-reports**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.mule.extension.BasicOperationsTestCase
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.551 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.mule.extension.BasicOperationsTestCase
initializationError(org.mule.extension.BasicOperationsTestCase)  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mule.runtime.api.deployment.meta.MuleServiceModel.getServiceProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.mule.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-basic-extension</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-extension</packaging>
    <name>Basic Extension</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mule.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-modules-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </parent>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-batch-ee</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0-20220622</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-20220622</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```